# How can I add a calculated column with different rows to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am getting some data on some websites with dataframe.
There is a column that name is "Open" it shows me open prices.
I am adding a new column to my frame which name is **Calculation**.
I am trying to make a calculation for today's open prices with yesterday's open prices.

How can I get yesterday's open prices? The code at the below, what should I write **QUESTIONMARK** area?

```
formul = df.get("Open") - **QUESTIONMARK**
df.insert(6, "Calculation", formul)
print(df.head())
```

Comment: Can you please post some data as well as an expected output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html):

```py
df['Open'] - df['Open'].shift()
```